# Cytoscape Context Menu

Tags: cytoscape

I am using Cytoscape Context Menus library (ie 'cytoscape-context-menus'). Great tool but seems there is no functionality to update an existing menu created. Let's say there is a menu with id="Status" associated with content="Started". How could I simply modify this content to "Ended" without having to remove this menu and created with new content ?